# Как в Log4Net создавать новый лог при каждом запуске программы и хранить не больше 3-х логов

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

Подскажите, как настроить Log4Net, что бы при каждом запуске генерировался новый лог, однако количество логов не может быть выше определенной цифры.
Т.е если я разрешаю 3 лога, то по достижению этой цифры он должен удалять старый лог и создавать новый.

Есть ли какой-нибудь метод у log4net, который принудительно прерывает текущий Log и создает новый в ходе выполнения программы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создавать новый лог при каждом запуске и при этом хранить не больше трех логов на диске вы можете использовать следующие ключи в конфиге:

```
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <!-- ... -->
        <rollingStyle value="Once"/> <!-- создавать новый лог при каждом запуске -->
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/> <!-- хранить максимум два бэкапа -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </appender>
```

Итого у вас будет храниться на диске один текущий лог + 2 бэкапа, то есть всего три файла.

По поводу метода, который принудительно прерывает текущий лог, и создает новый, мне такой не известен, и не думаю что он существует. Обычно не требуется такой контроль за логером. Вы можете выбрать правило, по которому должен создаваться новый лог с помощью параметра `rollingStyle` (при каждом запуске, при достижении определенного размера файла, через определенный промежуток времени), В большинстве сценариев одно из этих правил подходит, достаточно выбрать его и больше ни о чем не беспокоиться.